# Is it possible to dynamically update the value in a JavaScript object on button click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In JavaScript, I have created an object called `annualPlan`.

When someone submits the HTML form for a specific month, I want to be able to change the value in the object for a particular month.

For example, if someone submits August 21 and 200, I want `pAug` to be 500.

But if someone re-submits August 21 and 500, I want `pAug` to be 200.

The code snippet below was my attempt at doing this (actually it was more like attempt 100!).

What do you think?

```js
var planMonth;
var planAmount;




//create a custom ID value with the current time of form submit
var today = new Date();
var FullDate = today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1); //getMonth method starts from 0. Add 1 to get real month.
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
var dateTime = FullDate + " " + time


var annualPlan = {
  pJan: 0,
  pFeb: 0,
  pMarch: 0,
  pApril: 0,
  pJune: 0,
  pJuly: 0,
  pAugust: 0,
  pSept: 0,
  pOct: 0,
  pNov: 0,
  pDec: 0,
};

const addPlan = function(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  let planUpdate = {

    id: dateTime,
    Month: document.getElementById("PlanMonth").value,
    Amount: document.getElementById("PlanSave").value,
  }

  annualPlan.push(planUpdate);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();

  //console.log(annualPlan);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", addPlan);
});
```

```css
/* PAGE STRUCTURE START */

body {
  padding-left: 150px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#inputarea {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

input {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#formSection {
  padding-top: 30px;
}


/* PAGE STRUCTURE END */


/* FONT STYLING START */

#inputarea h3 {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #334058;
  font-size: 30px;
}


/* NAVIGATION AREA START */

* {
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100, 50, 21, 6);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100, 50, 21, 6);
  -moz-transition-property: all;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(100, 50, 21, 6);
}

.style-1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.btn {
  color: #fff;
  background: #3399cc;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background: #fff;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  color: #334058;
}


/* NAVIGATION AREA END */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grow Your Wealth</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="images/fav.ico">

</head>
<!-- Navigation Start -->

<nav class="style-1">
  <a href="index.html" class="btn">Home</a>
  <a href="appPage.html" class="btn">App Page</a>
</nav>

<!-- Navigation End -->

<section id="inputarea">
  <h3 id="section-header">Plan Input Area</h3>

  <form onsubmit=>
    <div id="formSection">
      <label for="PlanMonth">Month</label><br>
      <input type="month" name="PlanMonth" id="PlanMonth" value="2021-08">
    </div>
    <div id="formSection">
      <label for="PlanSave">Planned Saving for Month</label><br>
      <input type="number" name="PlanSave" id="PlanSave" value="200"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="formSection">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
  </form>



</section>



<!-- JS File -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *"But if someone re-submits August 21 and 500, I want pAug to be 200."* You want the value to stay 200??

Comment: Does your current code work?

Comment: No @epascarello, i want the value to be 500. Updated.

Comment: @Unmitigated It does not.

Comment: `annualPlan.push(planUpdate);` is problematic. Plain objects don't have a method called push. Do you want to use an array or set or what?

Comment: @Eldar - good question. My end goal is to be able to send the object info to a postgres DB. I picked objects for that reason. 

However, if I used an array, wouldnt the .push just add a new property instead of changing the property value?

Comment: @Vinn Do you just require the `annualPlan` object or you also need to store `planUpdate` object?

Comment: In hindsight, `planUpdate` isnt the needed. The goal is the get `annualPlan` object values to update on form submit.

Comment: you're able to access and change values on objects as you wish. `if(condition) { annualPlan.key=new_value; }`. -> continue with the rest of the flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to get the value of the month from the input and then find the corresponding month.

Example let's say you get the input date as `2021-08`.

1. We will extract the `08` out of it which is the month.
2. Next according to your month names, `08` corresponds to `pAugust`.
3. However we will choose `8-1` which is `7` because indexing starts from `0`,
4. Then we will get the existing value of that month using `annualPlan[month]` and then add the value of `amount` to it.

```js
var planMonth;
var planAmount;




//create a custom ID value with the current time of form submit
var today = new Date();
var FullDate = today.getDate() + "-" + (today.getMonth() + 1); //getMonth method starts from 0. Add 1 to get real month.
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes();
var dateTime = FullDate + " " + time


var annualPlan = {
  pJan: 0,
  pFeb: 0,
  pMarch: 0,
  pApril: 0,
  pMay:0,
  pJune: 0,
  pJuly: 0,
  pAugust: 0,
  pSept: 0,
  pOct: 0,
  pNov: 0,
  pDec: 0,
};

function findmonth(month){
// Get the month
month =  month.split('-')[1]
// Geta all the months
let months = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(annualPlan)
// Return the month according to the object annualPlan
return months[parseInt(month)-1]
}
const addPlan = function(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  let planUpdate = {

    id: dateTime,
    Month: document.getElementById("PlanMonth").value,
    Amount: document.getElementById("PlanSave").value,
  }
  // Get the existing value of the month
  let existingVal = annualPlan[findmonth(planUpdate.Month)];
  // Add the new value and update it to the obj
  annualPlan[findmonth(planUpdate.Month)] = parseInt(existingVal) +  parseInt(planUpdate.Amount)
  console.log(annualPlan)
  document.querySelector("form").reset();

  //console.log(annualPlan);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", addPlan);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grow Your Wealth</title>

  <link rel="icon" href="images/fav.ico">

</head>
<!-- Navigation Start -->

<nav class="style-1">
  <a href="index.html" class="btn">Home</a>
  <a href="appPage.html" class="btn">App Page</a>
</nav>

<!-- Navigation End -->

<section id="inputarea">
  <h3 id="section-header">Plan Input Area</h3>

  <form onsubmit=>
    <div id="formSection">
      <label for="PlanMonth">Month</label><br>
      <input type="month" name="PlanMonth" id="PlanMonth" value="2021-08">
    </div>
    <div id="formSection">
      <label for="PlanSave">Planned Saving for Month</label><br>
      <input type="number" name="PlanSave" id="PlanSave" value="200"><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="formSection">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button">
  </form>



</section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but a couple of things in this code doesn't look right, hopefully this helps you on your way.

```
<button onClick={doSomething}>My Button</button>

...

const data = {
  // values here
}

const doSomething = () => {
  data.example = // assign anything new here
}
```